# Why sometimes i cant set a class definition as slot in a s4 class?

Tags: r, class, r-s4

```
r=ks.test(x=rnorm(100), "dnorm")
class(r)
[1] "htest"


## Doesnt work, "htest" is class in stats
setClass("Jergon", representation(fit="htest"))
[1] "Jergon"
Warning message:
undefined slot classes in definition of "Jergon": fit(class "htest")


## works "lm" 
setClass("Jergon", representation(am="lm"))
[1] "Jergon"
```

Answer (score 8):

The result of `ks.test` is (from the documentation):

> A list with class "htest"

So, actually `"htest"` is not a *formal* class defined into a package, but simply, the class attribute of the list returned by `ks.test`, is set to `"htest"`.

To give an example, also the following code does't work (because `myclass` is not a formal class):

```
obj = list(foo=123)
class(obj) <- "myclass"

class(obj)
[1] "myclass"

setClass("Jergon", representation(foo="myclass"))
[1] "Jergon"
Warning message:
undefined slot classes in definition of "Jergon": foo(class "myclass")
```

To check if a class is *formally* defined  (and can be used as representation), you can use `getClassDef`, i.e. :

```
> getClassDef('htest')
NULL

> getClassDef('lm')
Virtual Class "lm" [package "methods"]

Slots:

Name:   .S3Class
Class: character

Extends: "oldClass"

Known Subclasses: 
Class "mlm", directly
Class "aov", directly
Class "glm", directly
Class "maov", by class "mlm", distance 2
Class "glm.null", by class "glm", distance 2
```

---

**EDIT :**

As correctly pointed out by @Martin Morgan, you can formally register an old-style S3 class using `setOldClass`. In fact the documentation says:

> Register an old-style (a.k.a. ‘S3’) class as a formally defined class.
>   The Classes argument is the character vector used as the class
>   attribute; in particular, if there is more than one string, old-style
>   class inheritance is mimicked. **Registering via setOldClass allows S3
>   classes to appear in method signatures, as a slot in an S4 class, or
>   as a superclass of an S4 class**.

Hence, this code works fine:

```
> setOldClass("htest")
> setClass("Jergon", representation(fit="htest"))
[1] "Jergon"
```

Comment: Nice answer; `setOldClass("htest")` tells the formal (S4) class system that you'd like to treat an object with a class attribute `htest` (S3 class) as an S4 class.

Comment: @MartinMorgan: good point, added to the question.